# Downloading GeckoFX older versions since Bitbucket repo turned private

Tags: c#, firefox-addon, geckofx

Since the bitbucket repo. of GeckoFX **turned private**, I am unable to download the older version of
GeckoFX say **37.0.1** .

Is there any source or way to do it to get **GeckoFX dlls** from the Browser itself or I will stuck on this catch22 thing.

I really need to implement it an only with that version it is possible the thing

I need to achieve. I need to add a plugin built on XPCOM which i not a part of latest Firefox libs.

PS. I have searched zillions of articles and stckoverflow links but could not find any argument supporting my problem.

Comment: Hold tight a few days... I'm sure hindlemail didn't mean to take it private permanently (if that's why it is 404'ing).

Comment: As to what happened... Bitbucket made all Mercurial repos inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a 37.0.1 version ever existed but there was v33 + v45.

[Softwareheritage](https://www.softwareheritage.org/) has archived all the repos:

You can find the geckofx stuff [here](https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/ge/geckofx/) including the downloadable zip files.

The official source can be found [here](https://hg.sr.ht/%7Ehindlemail/geckofx). Note this source contains tags for all the versions, so if you wanted to build v33, you would just update to the tag v33.0-0.10

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Softwareheritage, you find some older pre-packed versions on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=geckofx).
So, while you are able to fetch a earlier release of a specific package for your project using the package manager console in Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package GeckoFX -Version <press tab key for autocomplete> [*or a different package name]
```

you will probably not get far. Most of the GeckoFX releases on nuget are targeting more recent version (like v60, v45). But if you look a bit closer you will also find packages that are based on older releases like v33 (for [winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/geckofx-winforms/), and [core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/geckofx-core/)).